EBICS XML Signature in Javascript
it's my first time asking in stackoverflow
basically right now I am trying to implement EBICS
current progress in on HPB
I already created an XML with this format
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ebicsNoPubKeyDigestsRequest xmlns="urn:org:ebics:H004" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:org:ebics:H004 ebics_keymgmt_request_H004.xsd" Version="H004" Revision="1">
    <header authenticate="true">
        <static>
            <HostID>{HostID}</HostID>
            <Nonce>{Nonce}</Nonce>
            <Timestamp>{CurrentTimestamp}</Timestamp>
            <PartnerID>{ID}</PartnerID>
            <UserID>{ID}</UserID>
            <OrderDetails>
                <OrderType>HPB</OrderType>
                <OrderAttribute>DZHNN</OrderAttribute>
            </OrderDetails>
            <SecurityMedium>0000</SecurityMedium>
        </static>
        <mutable/>
    </header>
    <AuthSignature>
        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
            <ds:Reference URI="#xpointer(//*[@authenticate='true'])">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                <ds:DigestValue>....Digest value here...</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>...Signature value here....</ds:SignatureValue>
    </AuthSignature>
    <body/>
</ebicsNoPubKeyDigestsRequest>

But it always return Signature invalid
after check with the bank, they say the DigestValue is not match with the one they generated
Here is the code to generate Digest Value
// **************** Import library ****************
const crypto = require('crypto');
const C14n =    require('xml-crypto/lib/c14n-canonicalization').C14nCanonicalization;
const { DOMParser, XMLSerializer } = require('@xmldom/xmldom');
const xpath = require('xpath');

/**
 * To return digest result based on hash algorithm
 * @param {*} data: string that will be hash
 * @param {*} algorithm: algorithm used, default is sha256
 * @returns 
 */
function digestWithHash(data, algorithm = 'sha256') {
  const digestHash = forge.md.sha256.create();

  digestHash.update(data);

  // return digestHash.digest().toHex()
  return crypto.createHash(algorithm)
    .update(data)
    .digest();
}

/**
 * Generate Digest Value
 * @param {*} doc 
 */
function GenerateDigestValue(doc) {
  // **************** get the xml node, where the digested value is supposed to be
  const nodeDigestValue = doc.getElementsByTagName('ds:DigestValue')[0];

  // **************** canonicalize the node that has authenticate='true' attribute
  const contentToDigest = xpath
    .select("//*[@authenticate='true']", doc)
    .map(x => new C14n().process(x))
    .join('');

  // **************** fix the canonicalization
  const fixedContent = contentToDigest
    .replace(/&#xD;/g, '')
    .replace(
      /xmlns="urn:org:ebics:H004"/g,
      'xmlns="urn:org:ebics:H004" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"',
    );

  

  // **************** Write file as type XML
  fs.writeFileSync("./xml/Canonized-HPB-header.xml", fixedContent);


  // **************** Digest content using sha-256 & encode it to base-64
  nodeDigestValue.textContent = digestWithHash(fixedContent)
    .toString('base64')
    .trim();

  return doc;
}

Here is the main problem
I already tried package called C14N as you can see in the code but still getting same error result. It also seems doing nothing unless I add replace there
Here is the error that I got from the bank
Image
Is there any implementation in javascript to generate this SignedXML?
I already search everywhere & most of them are either still stuck in INI & HIA or is in different programming language
NodeJs version: v20.14.0
 "@xmldom/xmldom": "^0.8.10",
"archiver": "^7.0.1",
"axios": "^1.7.2",
"luxon": "^3.4.4",
"node-forge": "^1.3.1",
"uuid": "^10.0.0",
"xml-crypto": "^4.0.1",
"xpath": "0.0.32"

Thank you :)

Does code work if you use Postman?  Postman has a control panel where you can get the entire HTML Request.  If postman works than the issue is with missing HTTP Headers in your request.  If postman fails than take the entire request from postman control panel and use an online validator the checks schema to validate the request.  The online checker may give a schema error that can help determine the issue.

The request actually already ok & received by the Bank, the problem is that they say the DigestValue from the request is not match with DigestValue they generated based on XML request
They even gave me the example & showing my XML request which mean it's working
I will update the post with the error I got

I do not think it is a signature error.  Instead an Authentication error according to the link.  It is a two step authentication.  Step one is to get a token/cookie.  Step two is to make request.  The error indicates the token is invalid.  Could of expired.  See https://www.epicgames.com/help/en-US/c-Category_EpicAccount/c-AccountSecurity/two-factor-authentication-2fa-and-how-to-enable-it-a000084651

It could be the Ids in the header are not correct.  Header are important because there are three headers that could make a different 1) Content-Type 2) Compression GZIP 3) User Agent.  I think the hash isn't matching because you may be using a different IDs.

this one is integration with bank called EBICS, so I think you might miss it as EPIC (game)
yes, you are right
it's not signature error, the bank already received my request so the request is working properly
the problem is when they do the same canonicalization process, the result it's not same as the one in my request, that's why they say it's error, this one they said it to me directly, but the error still display like that
the main problem is how I can do the same canonicalization, since off course the bank will not give me information how they do canonicalization for the XML

It is either the order you are doing the signature or white character (line feed) that is different.

It's the problem in the DigestValue like I mentioned before, the signature already ok, for the white character is not solving either
but now it's already ok, I already receive the response & able to do the HPB
thanks for the help :)

the problem is on canonicalization process
I just need to add more attributes & it can send HPB after that
  const contentToSign = new C14n()
  .process(select('//ds:SignedInfo', doc)[0])
  .replace(
    'xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"',
  'xmlns="urn:org:ebics:H004" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"',
)

